# How to set breakpoint at the very beginning of a method call in Xcode so that I can check $rdi $rsi etc?

Tags: xcode, lldb

I would like to set breakpoint at the very beginning of a method call    so that I can check it's $rdi $rsi etc.

In Xcode, when I set a    symbolic breakpoint at a method call say -[HelperClass    doThingWithBlock:], it stops at the first line of the method body,    which is already several instructions after the beginning of the    method call, as shown in the disassembly of the method call below.

```
DebugBlock`-[HelperClass doThingWithBlock:]:
        0x109844aa0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
        0x109844aa1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
        0x109844aa4 <+4>:  subq   $0x30, %rsp
        0x109844aa8 <+8>:  leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax
        0x109844aac <+12>: movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
        0x109844ab0 <+16>: movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
        0x109844ab4 <+20>: movq   $0x0, -0x18(%rbp)
        0x109844abc <+28>: movq   %rax, %rdi
        0x109844abf <+31>: movq   %rdx, %rsi
        0x109844ac2 <+34>: callq  0x109844c74               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
        0x109844ac7 <+39>: leaq   0x15a2(%rip), %rax        ; @"hi"
        0x109844ace <+46>: movl   $0x16, %ecx
        0x109844ad3 <+51>: movl   %ecx, %edx
    ->  0x109844ad5 <+53>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rsi
        0x109844ad9 <+57>: movq   %rsi, %rdi
        0x109844adc <+60>: movq   %rsi, -0x20(%rbp)
        0x109844ae0 <+64>: movq   %rax, %rsi
        0x109844ae3 <+67>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
        0x109844ae7 <+71>: callq  *0x10(%rax)
        0x109844aea <+74>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
        0x109844aec <+76>: movl   %ecx, %esi
        0x109844aee <+78>: leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdx
        0x109844af2 <+82>: movq   %rdx, %rdi
        0x109844af5 <+85>: movb   %al, -0x21(%rbp)
        0x109844af8 <+88>: callq  0x109844c74               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
        0x109844afd <+93>: addq   $0x30, %rsp
        0x109844b01 <+97>: popq   %rbp
        0x109844b02 <+98>: retq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason's advice is good for more complex problems, but this is a pretty common requirement, so `break set` has an option specifically to control pushing the breakpoint past the prologue:

(lldb) break set -n main --skip-prologue 0

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Hah, I was looking specifically for an option like that but missed it in the `help br s` output.

Answer (score 1):

lldb will advance the breakpoint location to the first source line in the function when you have debug information.  The idea is that most people with source level information are more interested in printing the arguments with their names instead of looking at the registers that were used to pass them in.

If you were working with a simple C function, you could set an address breakpoint evaluating the function name to an address, e.g.

```
(lldb) br s -n main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 11 at a.c:3, address = 0x0000000100000f8b
(lldb) br s -a `main`
Breakpoint 2: address = 0x0000000100000f80
(lldb)
```

The backtick notation `` evaluates the expression in the backtick to an address/value.  And `breakpoint set --address` works as you'd expect.

There's even some special magic built in where you don't need backticks for things that are expecting an address, like `br s -a`.  You can do `br s -a main` and it will work -- and as a very special bonus, you can add offsets to functions here like `br s -a main+5` which is normally not a valid C expression.

Unfortunately we're working with an objc method `-[HelperClass doThingWithBlock:]` which you can't drop in as an expression like I did with `main`.  I think in this case you're going to need to find the address of it yourself, e.g. you might disassemble an instruction at the start like `dis -c 1 -n '-[ViewController setRepresentedObject:]'`, and then feed that address into `br s -a`.

Comment: Great answer. 'br s -a' paired with 'dis -n' is powerful.